# O que quer dizer backref no relacionamento de tabelas many to many no SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Estou criando um modelo de banco de dados no meu models.py para minha aplicação em Flask. 
Tenho uma tabela Usuário, e cada usuário pode ter vários instrumentos, e um instrumento pode ter vários usuários.

Na documentação do **SQLAlchemy** e do **Flask-SQLAlchemy** eles recomendam criar uma tabela e não um modelo como é criado para usuário parar dar suporte a esse relacionamento, fiz conforme o que a documentação recomenda, mas ainda não entendi ao que se refere o parâmetro backref.

```
usuario_instrumento = db.Table('usuario_instrumento',
    db.Column('instrumento_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instrumento.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('usuario_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usuario.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Usuario(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    instrumentos = db.relationship('Instrumento', secondary=usuario_instrumento, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('usuarios', lazy=True))

class Instrumento(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode entender o atributo `backref` como sendo um atributo na tabela que você especificou como a outra parte do relacionamento, no seu caso é a tabela `Instrumento`.

Se torna muito útil na hora de fazer querys no relacionamento, pois a partir dessa declaração, você poderá fazer uma query como `Instrumento.usuarios`, para saber quais usuários estão associados a um determinado instrumento.

Note que esse relacionamento pode ser feito em qualquer uma das duas tabelas, vai depender apenas do que faz mais sentido para o seu caso de uso. Caso você queira fazer a query inversa, (`Usuario.instrumentos`), para saber quais usuários estão associados a um determinado elemento, basta adicionar o mesmo tipo de atributo na tabela Instrumento:

```
usuarios = db.relationship('Usuario', secondary=usuario_instrumento, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('instrumentos', lazy=True))
```

Espero ter ajudado e bom aprendizado!